# Using OpenCV, how to find the values of HSV channels of the "masked region" in a masked image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, android

Using OpenCV4Android, how can I get the HSV channels of the first pixel of the *masked region* in a masked image (`dilatedMat` in the following snippet)? **I know that we'd get the HSV channel values of first pixel by `hsvMat.get(0,0)` but I don't know how to apply this to the masked region only, rather than the entire `Mat`.**

For example, following is a function to which a camera frame is passed as an argument, and I have generated a mask, but how should I proceed from there?

***NOTE:*** Please keep in mind that the masked region is Not a rectangle, it has an irregular shape.

```
private void detectColoredBlob (Mat rgbaFrame) { 
        Mat hsvImage = new Mat(); 
        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaFrame, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);

        Mat maskedImage = new Mat(); 
        Scalar lowerThreshold = new Scalar(85, 50, 20); 
        Scalar upperThreshold = new Scalar(135, 255, 77); 
        Core.inRange(hsvImage, lowerThreshold, upperThreshold, maskedImage);

        Mat dilatedMat= new Mat(); 
        Imgproc.dilate(maskedImage, dilatedMat, new Mat() ); 

        //****************WHAT NOW???**************
     }
```

Comment: You can, for example, compute the centroid `(x1, y1)` of each blob in the dilatedMat (see `findContours` or `connectedComponents[WithStats]`), and then access position `x1, y1` in the `hsvImage`

Comment: @Miki I did try findContours by List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(); Imgproc.findContours(dilatedMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);. But again confused. I can't figure out how I would apply the get(0,0) function (used to get the HSV channels of the pixel located at (0,0) position) on the region inside the contour, rather than on the entire image.

Comment: @Miki I should also mention that my actual requirement is getting the _average_ HSV value of the contour found (Assume only one contour for simplicity, b/c I have already found the largest contour from the found contours). Since I already know how to compute average HSV of a `Mat` (like they have done from Line 140 to 144 [here](https://github.com/nehiljain/opencv4android/blob/master/samples/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java)), so for simplicity, I talked about the first (one located at `(0,0)`) pixel in the question.

Comment: Just thinking out loud--you could put a bounding rect around the contour in the HSV image, and iterate through each pixel in that bounding rect.  If that pixel is inside the contour, include it in the computation of the average.  Maybe there are more efficient ways to do it?